# regex to check if string contains one word with symbols

Tags: regex

This Regex checks if the string contains one word but it reads word with symbols like ' and "" two words.. how to allow symbols to this Regex?

```
WordCount = New Regex("\w+").Matches(line).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one symbol, like **"don't"**, or **"girl's"** you can try

```
\w+['"]?\w*
```

Which means, the word has to start with character, may ends with **'** or **"**

Comment: it gives me error if i enclose it in "" like this ("\w+['"]?\w*"). the second quotation mark marks the end of the pattern not the last "

Comment: May I know under what environment are you executing the regex?